# Convert two-dimensional ArrayList to two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a two-dimensional ArrayList of Integers (say list)
`ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>()`       //*assume values are* assigned
I want to convert it to a two-dimensional array of primitive int in Java. How can I achieve that using steam as we do in the one-dimensional case

```
ArrayList<Integer> x =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
int[] arr = x.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
```

Comment: Shouldn't `x` be a list of lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
int[][] arr = list.stream()
                  .map(l -> l.stream()
                             .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                             .toArray())
                  .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

Each inner `List` is mapped to an `int[]` (by first converting it to an `IntStream`), and then you convert your `Stream<int[]>` to an `int[][]`.